# How to create new navigation bar from clicked li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

This question is kind of puzzle, I know its not so easy, I would like to create new navigation link based on clicked li, for example

```
<nav id="nav-main">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li>Others
            <ul>
                <li>Employee Portal
                <ul>
                 <li><a href="">Current Staff</a></li>
                 <li><a href="">Retired Staff</a></li>
                 <li><a href="">Staff Profile</a></li>
                </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Suppose If I click on "Home" I would like to create new nav bar like below**

```
<nav id="nav_others">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Same way if I click on "Staff Profile"**

```
<nav id="nav_others">
        <ul>
          <li>Others
             <ul>
                <li>Employee Portal
                  <ul>
                       <li><a href="">Staff Profile</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        <ul>
</nav>
```

I don't know how many parent and children elements, my navigation element will have, if anyone here knows how to achieve this using jquery or javascript please share your solutions.

Thank You

Comment: I'll start you off: `$('li').click(function (ev){ ... });` Now try it yourself first, then come back and ask specific questions if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following div into your code(After nav-main):

```
<nav id="nav_others">
  <ul></ul>
</nav>
```

And use the following Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.main').click(function(e){
       var val = $(this).text();
       $('#nav_others ul').append('<li class="prev"><a href="#">'+val+'</a></li>');
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```